# Magento 2 Create Controller With No Theme?

Tags: magento2, blocks, theme, controllers, magento2.3.5

Is it possible to create a controller with Magento 2 that doesn't have the admin menus/navbars?
Essentially I want the page to return just the HTML I write and not put anything else?

I considered just throwing the HTML into JSON and decoding it later but that seems kind of like a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have gathered many controllers that all use different outputs. The first one is the most commonly used and it does interact with the layout. The other can output plain text, json and build your own blocks

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Execute action based on request and return result
     *
     * Note: Request will be added as operation argument in future
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultFactory->create();
    }
```

}

// plain response not using any layout

```
class Alternative extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('content-type', 'text/plain');
        $this->getResponse()->appendBody('this is a plain response');
    }
}
```

// json response not using any layout

```
class Alternative extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    public function __construct(
    Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonResultFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->jsonResultFactory = $jsonResultFactory;
}

public function execute()
{
    $data = ['test'=> 'this is the response'];

    $result = $this->jsonResultFactory->create();
    $result->setData($data);
    return $result;
}
}
```

// build your html within the controller

```
class BlockWithinController extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $layout = $this->_view->getLayout();
        $block = $layout->createBlock(\Mbs\Answer\Block\Random::class);

        $this->getResponse()->appendBody($block->toHtml());
    }
}
```

// BUild a controller in the backend that outputs a json message:
https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/backendcontroller/src

Comment: Thanks, this went above and beyond!

Comment: Out of curiosity, I am attempting to use this in a backend route, so I have changed the extends/implements to `use Magento\Backend\App\Action;` and
`use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;` but using your plain response it gives me a 401

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.magecheck.com/magento-backend-controller, if still not working, I’ll take a look tonight

Comment: Yeah unfortunately even following that I get a 401 :/ It may be something else in my code that is causing it so I will continue to play around with it today.

Comment: I have updated my answer, not ideal, the the repository I have added does build a backend controller and its work s on my machine